How do I make sure mathematical expectation is a linear function when my sample space is countably infinite?
Let us have a probability space $⟨Ω; \mathcal{F}; P⟩$ where:

the sample space $Ω$ is countably infinite — say $ℕ$
the algebra of events $\mathcal{F}$ is simply $\mathcal{P}Ω$
the probability measure $P$ is, say, a falling exponential function $n ↦ (1/2)^n$ scaled with $α = 1/2$ such that $Σ_i^ℕP_i = 1$

So, let our example be $S ≔ ⟨ℕ; \mathcal{P} ℕ; n ↦ α(1/2)^n⟩$. This seems to me to fulfill all the requirements of a probability space.
Let mathematical expectation $\mathbb{E}$ of a random variable $X: ℕ →_S ℝ$ on $S$ be defined in a standard way:
$$\mathbb{E}_S (X) ≔ Σ^ℕ_i P_{Si} X_i$$
Now take $2^{(·)}: ℕ → ℝ ≔ i ↦ 2^i$. It has the type of a random variable on $S$. Say we admit it as a random variable $2_S^{(·)}: ℕ →_S ℝ$. Now our $\mathbb{E}_S$ is not even a function, much less a linear function, because:
$$\mathbb{E}_S 2_S^{(·)} = Σ^ℕ_i P_{Si} 2^i = Σ_i^ℕ α(1/2)^i 2^i = Σ_i^ℕ α = ∞$$
So, if we want $\mathbb{E}_S$ to be a function, we have to accept that not all functions of type $Ω_S → ℝ$ are random variables on $S$. We need to restrict what functions we admit to be random variables.

For example, we can say that a random variable on $S$ is a function $r: Ω_S → ℝ$ equipped with a proof that $\mathbb{E}_Sr$ absolutely converges. But then, if we want $\mathbb{E}_S$ to be linear, we must first prove that the set of such restricted random variables is still a linear space — maybe a subspace of the linear space of all functions $Ω_S → ℝ$. It is not clear how to do that.

Or maybe we can find an admittance requirement that implies that $\mathbb{E}_S$ is defined and makes random variables a vector space in an obvious way. It is not clear what such a requirement may be.


What can I do? How do I define my random variables?

Maybe. Are $L^1$ something like integrable functions? I think there are some functions that are not integrable but still have well defined mathematical expectation when understood as random variables. Can you write an answer or refer me to an explanation elsewhere? It would be great to see some proofs.

Added an answer below with an explanation and a reference to wikipedia. I'm not sure what you mean by "there are some functions that are not integrable but still have well-defined mathematical expectation", can you give an example?

A common definition is the vector space of $L^1$ (or more generally $L^p$ for $p \in [1, \infty]$) functions on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. These are defined to be $\mathcal{F}$-measurable functions $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (or sometimes $\mathbb{C}$) such that $\mathbb{E}(|X|) < \infty$. They form a vector subspace $\tilde{L}$ of all functions $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. The non-trivial fact to be checked is that $\tilde{L}$ is closed under pointwise addition, but if $X, Y \in \tilde{L}$ then
$$\mathbb{E}(|X + Y|) \le \mathbb{E}(|X| + |Y|) = \mathbb{E}(|X|) + \mathbb{E}(|Y|) < \infty .$$
The subspace $\tilde{L}$ also comes with a seminorm $X \mapsto \mathbb{E}(|X|)$ (the above calculation verifies the triangle inequality). For the $P$ you specify in the question, since each point of $\Omega$ has positive measure it is actually a norm, so we can take $L^1 = \tilde{L}$. In general, we need to pass to the quotient by the subspace $\tilde{L}_0$ consisting of those $X$ for which $\mathbb{E}(|X|) = 0$. Since $|X| \ge 0$ everywhere, $X \in \tilde{L}_0$ precisely means that $X$ vanishes almost everywhere wrt $P$, in particularly $\tilde{L}_0$ is a linear subspace. (In general, given a vector space $V$ with a seminorm $||\cdot||$, the subset $\{x \in V \mid ||x|| = 0\}$ is a linear subspace.)
So we define $L^1 = L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) = \tilde{L}/\tilde{L}_0$, which comes with the norm $[X] \mapsto \mathbb{E}(|X|)$. Note that $\mathbb{E} : L^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ now has the desired codomain, using $|\mathbb{E}(X)| \le \mathbb{E}(|X|)$, and is linear. It is also continuous (wrt the norm topology on the domain) because of the same bound.
This construction seems to be what you roughly describe in the first bullet point, but in fact it is not hard to check that $\tilde L$ and therefore $L^1$ is a linear space.

Let us take a look at $Δ_1: ℕ → ℝ ≔ i ↦ 1$, the constant 1 function. This function is the identity element of point-wise multiplication — therefore, its mathematical expectation with the probability measure $P_S$ (or even any probability measure) is $1$. So, $\mathbb{E}_S$ is defined at $Δ_1$, even though it is not integrable. This is what I had in mind when I said that there are functions that are not integrable but have a well defined mathematical expectation. Restricting ourselves to integrable functions is good but not great.

@IgnatInsarov why do you think this function is not integrable with respect to $P$? $\mathbb{E}(|\Delta_1|) = \mathbb{E}(\Delta_1) = 1$. Indeed constant (or more generally bounded) functions will be integrable wrt any probability measure (or equivalently any finite measure). Note that the definition of $L^1$ depends on $P$ and is not considering only the functions integrable under the counting measure.

I see. I missed that your definition of $\tilde{L}$ depends on $P$. So, we generally get different vector spaces of random variables for different probability spaces. For example, a probability space which measure is zero outside of some region, say $±1$, admits functions that are unbounded but bounded within this region as random variables, even while they would be rejected for my example $S$. Right?

@IgnatInsarov Note that if $P(A) = 0$ for some $A \subset \Omega$, then $E(X) = E(X|\Omega - A)$ and two $L^1$ functions that agree away from $A$ will represent the same element of the vector space $L^1$. So it does not at all matter what functions do on $A$ as long as they are measurable.

There is still something I do not understand. $\mathbb{E}_S$ is linear on ${X : Ω → ℝ \mid \mathbb{E}_S X < ∞}$, but $\mathbb{E}_S |·|$ is not linear on this set. If it was linear, then $\mathbb{E}_S |·| = 0$ would have been a linear condition and so would have defined a linear subspace. But since it is not linear, $\mathbb{E}_S |·| = 0$ is not a linear condition and so does not define a linear subspace. Therefore we cannot take the quotient as you ask. $\mathbb{E}_S (·) = 0$, meanwhile, allows functions that have mathematical expectation zero while being zero almost nowhere.

@IgnatInsarov $\mathbb{E}_S |X| = 0$ does define a linear subspace: if $X$ and $Y$ are a.e. $0$ then so are $X + Y$ and $c X$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$. More generally, the vanishing set of a semi-norm is always a linear subspace, this follows from the triangle inequality (and homogeneity).

Yes, you are right. We have $0 ≤ \mathbb{E}_S |X + Y| ≤ \mathbb{E}_S |X| + \mathbb{E}_S |Y|$, so when $\mathbb{E}_S |X| = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}_S |Y| = 0$ we have specifically $0 ≤ \mathbb{E}_S |X + Y| ≤ 0 ⇒ \mathbb{E}_S |X + Y| = 0$. I was wrong about all linear conditions being themselves necessarily linear. Can I ask you to add something to your answer that would make this situation easier to understand for the future reader?

@IgnatInsarov sure, added
